# Do C++ compilers generate a def ctor if the class was not initialized?

Tags: c++, destructor, default-constructor

I have written a utility class (acts as a helper class, I guess) that has only a few *static* member functions to be used in another class. It does not have any non-static members (variables or functions). So it also doesn't have any **explicit ctors** or **dtor**.

And the question is, does my compiler (GCC v11.2 and -std=c++20) still generate an **implicit default ctor and a dtor** for the utility class? If it does, then how should I prevent it from doing so? since I haven't initialized any instance of that class in my code.

Comment: If you don't want the class to be instantiated, you can explicitly delete the constructor: `private: MyClass() = delete;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'm slightly side-stepping your question in lieu of providing unsolicited advice) If you have a collection of `static` functions and your class does not require any state

```
class Example
{
public:
    static void Foo();
    static int Bar();
};
```

then you should likely not be using a `class` in the first place, rather these should probably be free functions in a namespace

```
namespace Example
{
    void Foo();
    int Bar();
}
```

which still allows you to invoke them as `Example::Foo()` and `Example::Bar()` but now you don't have to worry about someone trying to instantiate your "class" since that's not what you intended to design it for.

Comment: I believe that what you offered is the alternative to the class-type that I've been looking for! Namespaces! Now I have to make some changes to the code. But one more question: Will I have to change anything in the other classes? Or should I just change **class utility** to a namespace? Also, where should I place the said namespace? In a seperate header file?

Comment: You should be able to basically change `class` to `namespace` and drop the usages of `static` and that's about it, no changes needed by any of the callers. You can place this wherever you'd like, for example having the declarations in a .h file and definitions in a cpp file.

Comment: One thing to look out for is that if you were providing definitions of functions in the header file, you'll have to mark them `inline` when you convert from static member functions of a class to free functions in a namespace to avoid a one-definition rule violation. If you were just doing declarations in a header and implementations in a source file, you don't have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As is already mentioned, you should be using namespaces for this type of context. That being said, to answer your question, the answer is "not really". The compiler must "create" one, but it doesn't have to generate code for it.

I cannot find anything explicitly stating this in the standard, however, if you create a simple class which just has static functions, and view the generated assembly code, you can see that no constructor is created. Even if you attempt to instantiate the object, using either automatic or dynamic variables, no code is generated. Simply put, since there's nothing that a default constructor would even do, there's no reason for the compiler to generate any code.

You can view this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/noddbdqq9) using gcc 11.2 with C++20 enable. Note that I have optimizations turned off, just to show that it's not the `-O3` which removes the call.

Comment: I checked that link which you provided. Yes you are right. The compiler doesn't generate an implicit default constructor for the class even if it was instantiated. I also added a member variable (of type int) to the class to see if it will force the compiler to generate a constructor but no. It didn't have any effects. There was no constructor in the assembly code.

Comment: @digito_evo, yes, until you start initializing variables, then the default constructor has nothing to do, so no code is required.